# Editing class init parameter as a list

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to figure out how to properly append to the friends list initialised in the constructor and have tried a few different angles.  I know that `self.friends.append(SocialNetworkUser)` is the issue, but not sure how to properly modify.

```
class SocialNetworkUser:

    potentialFriends = []

    def __init__(self, name, friends=[]):
        self.name = name

    def befriend(self, SocialNetworkUser):
        self.potentialFriends.append(SocialNetworkUser)
        if self in SocialNetworkUser.potentialFriends:
            self.friends.append(SocialNetworkUser)
```

Comment: You probably should start with not using a class name as a parameter name

Comment: I'm trying to take an instance of the same class type as the argument for the method.  Like take self and another SocialNetworkUser as the arguments and then compare/modify each others friends lists

Comment: That's fine and all, but that isn't what your code is doing. The parameter name doesn't have to match the class. Also, `self.potentialFriends` isn't the correct reference to `SocialNetworkUser.potentialFriends` and `self.friends` is never initialize despite what you're trying to do with `def __init__(self, name, friends=[]):`

Comment: For starters, you need `self.friends = []` in `__init__`. Then read http://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/476. Finally, this whole deal with `potentialFriends` seems somewhat nonsensical; but I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Thanks for tips guys, relatively new to classes so will look into it more